# How to turn a promise resolving with an observable to this observable?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have an API method which returns a promise resolving with an observable of `Item`s. Using the means of RxJS how can I turn this promise into the observable of `Item`s? In the language of code:

```
get items$(): Observable<Item> {
    const sourcePromise: Promise<Observable<Item>> = apiService.getItemsObservable();
    const sourceObservable: Observable<Observable<Item>> = from(sourcePromise);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: what you doing looks correct to me

Comment: @FanCheung but what should I do next? I need to return an `Observable<Item>` , not `Observable<Observable<Item>>`

Comment: you can just return `apiService.getItemsObservable()`, no need other conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by using mergeMap. This will remove one layer of observables:

```
const levelDown$ = SourceObservable.pipe(
  mergeMap(val=>val)
);
```